# Is there a difference between pure binary and binary?

Tags: terminology, encoding-scheme

In some books and on the internet I occasionally find "pure binary" and "binary" on its own, is there a difference between these two terms? If so, can someone describe briefly what they are?

Comment: What is the context?

Comment: @Aryabhata I found it to be in a section about Gray Code, where only the term "pure binary" is used, while "binary" is used in the rest of the book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing here for lack of context, but I think the following distinction is reasonable.

A *binary* encoding is anything that maps stuff to bit strings. There are [many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number#See_also), including two's complement, IEEE float, ASCII, and so on.

*Pure binary* probably refers to bland natural numbers written in base two, i.e.
if $n_{(2)} = a_k\dots a_0$ then

$\qquad\displaystyle n = \sum_{i=0}^{k} 2^ia_i$.

Comment: So pure binary refers to binary pattern that has not been modified in any way or is not a fixed-point binary number and not a signed integer, etc. Just the natural denary number converted to binary?

Comment: That's what I'm saying, but I can't promise that everybody will use the terms like that in every context.

Answer (score 1):

The only contexts I know where *pure binary* is used when referencing the C standard which has a definition for the concept

> A positional representation for integers that uses the binary digits 0 and 1, in which the values
>   represented by successive bits are additive, begin with 1, and are multiplied by successive integral
>   powers of 2, except perhaps the bit with the highest position.

The rationale for the C standard mentions the desire to avoid things like [Gray code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code).